# How to scrape the data inside multiple table using php code

Tags: php, web-scraping, using

How to scrape the data inside the table using php code

I already tried this

```
 $row = $html->find('//div[@id="content"]/table[3]/tr[2]/td');
foreach($row as $value) {
    $values[] = trim($value->textContent);
}
```

[image]

```
enter code here
```

Comment: please add details of what you have already tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. using java query

```
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
        if($(this).text() == "Carbon Black Metallic")
            $(this).text('');
    });
```

Comment: Give class on that table which you want to replace td text. 
$(" class1 td").filter(function() { ....});

<table class="class1">......</table>
<table>......</table>